# Use result of WITH statement inside a subquery at Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

The following query is working fine:

```sql
WITH
    (
        SELECT 1
    ) AS test_val
SELECT
    test_val,
    count()
FROM system.tables

┌─test_val─┬─count()─┐
│        1 │      93 │
└──────────┴─────────┘
```

But if I'm rewriting the same with subquery:

```sql
WITH
    (
        SELECT 1
    ) AS test_val
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        test_val,
        count()
    FROM system.tables
)
```

There is an error:

```
Code: 47. DB::Exception: Received from clickhouse-server:9000. DB::Exception: Missing columns: 'test_val' while processing query: 'SELECT test_val, count() FROM system.tables', required columns: 'test_val', source columns: 'total_bytes' ...
```

(I know that It's useless query, I just post it here for an example)

How can I use `test_val` inside a subquery ?

Clickhouse version: 20.11

Comment: CH v22.3 and possibly some older versions support this syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that `WITH` can be moved into the nested query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(
    WITH
    (
        SELECT 1
    ) AS test_val
    SELECT
        test_val,
        count()
    FROM system.tables
)
```